# My package manager is broken, index files are missing

Tags: apt, update-manager

I've a problem with package-manager in my Ubuntu 12.04. I've read some answer and I find this possible solution:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade --fix-missing
```

I've try the solution proposed and I obtain this error message:(the message is in Italian but I put English translation in [])

```
Errore GPG: http:/ /it.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release: Le seguenti firme non erano valide[the sequent signs are not valid]: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key W: Impossibile recuperare[impossible to recover] http:/ /it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Index Nessuna voce Hash nel file Release[anyone Hash element in file Release] /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Index

W: Impossibile recuperare[impossible to recover] http:/ /it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/i18n/Index Nessuna voce Hash nel file Release[anyone Hash element in file Release] /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_i18n_Index

W: Impossibile recuperare[impossible to recover] http:/ /it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/i18n/Index Nessuna voce Hash nel file Release[anyone Hash element in file Release] /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_restricted_i18n_Index

W: Impossibile recuperare[impossible to recover] http:/ /it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Index Nessuna voce Hash nel file Release[anyone Hash element in file Release] /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_i18n_Index

E: Impossibile scaricare alcuni file di indice: saranno ignorati o verranno usati quelli vecchi.[Is impossible download some index file: they will be ignored or will be used the old ones.]>>
```

I'don't understand how resolve this problem anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following website
http://www.howtoforge.com/generate_sources.list_with_source_o_matic
and edited my sources.list

I had a similar problem that I resolved by removing an additional sources line I had put in.

Hope this helps

Comment: While this could technically answer the question, you should include the steps needed to solve the problem in your answer.